# Android Gradle - Building library module generates unexpected .aar

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

I am currently working on setting up a multi-module project, with the following structure:

```
Project Root
  |- app/
    |- src/
    |- build.gradle
  |- lib
    |- src/
    |- build.gradle
  |- build.gradle
  |- gradle.properties
  |- settings.gradle
```

While the library module builds as expected, I get the following build error for the app module:

```
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:prepareProjectRootLib10Library'.
> File 'C:\projects\Project Root\lib\build\outputs\aar\lib-1.0.aar' specified for property 'bundle' does not exist.
```

As far as my build script goes, I do not think I am doing anything wrong with my build scripts. At the same time, when I look for the generate `.aar` for my library project, I instead find a `lib-1.0-SNAPSHOT.aar` file instead, which explains the problem. While manually renaming that file to match what the build script expects fixes the issue, I need a solution that does require manual work. Is there a way to modify the build script such that the application module can get the library project files it needs?

If it helps, below is `app/build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 20
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src/main/resources']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['src/assets']
        }
        androidTest {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/androidTest/java']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src/androidTest/resources']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['src/assets']
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':lib')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
}
```

And this is `lib/build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 20
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src/main/resources']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['src/assets']
        }
        androidTest {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/androidTest/java']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src/androidTest/resources']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['src/assets']
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Have you found any solution to this?